# Transformations on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

I'm trying to work out what the transformation $T:z \rightarrow -\frac{1}{z}$ does (eg reflection in a line, rotation around a point etc). Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! I've tried seeing what it does to $1$ and $i$ but is hasn't helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what happens on $\;S^1:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=1\}\;$ ? What inside, what outside...?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [circle inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion), followed by a reflection over the y axis.

Comment: The map $z \mapsto -z$ is not a reflection over the $y$ axis.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The map $z\mapsto \frac 1z$ is a circle inversion and a reflection over the $x$ axis, the map $z\mapsto -z$ is a reflection over both axises.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

What does negation do? Then what does taking the reciprocal do to the length and the angle? Note that you will need to know what [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_inversion) is, to describe what happens to the length.